# Pretraining in Returnn

Tags: returnn

I was trying to train a simple Uni-directional Encoder in returnn, using this config `https://github.com/rwth-i6/returnn-experiments/blob/master/2018-asr-attention/librispeech/full-setup-attention/returnn.config` after removing the decoder and bw layers of the encoder.

But none of my experiments are converging without pre-training. I have tried with different learning rates and different time reduction factors. As mentioned in [1st paper] ((https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.03294) and [2nd paper] (https://openreview.net/forum?id=S1gp9v_jsm) pretraining makes training stable but in my case none of my models converge without pretraining.

Can someone suggest me any possible workaround ?

Comment: What is the problem with pretraining?

Comment: Thanks for you comment Albert. Actually I am trying to reconstruct some baselines using returnn. And none of my reference's use a pretraining strategy. But in my case none of my models converge without pretraining. Even simple models such as Uni Directional LSTM Encoder does not converge. I want to know if you would have some suggestions over this observation

Comment: Bidirectional LSTM probably is more stable/easy to train. If you do not want to use pretraining, the initialization matters much more, so you probably should tune that as well. Then of course the usual hyper params like learning rate. Esp some lr warmup is probably important, and play around with that. But in any case, as we observed, without pretraining, it's much harder to get it to convergence, and also more unstable.

Comment: Other things to try: Lower the learning rate(s). Make the warmup phase longer. Play around with different initialization schemes. Maybe init the params with smaller values.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it seems the main question is: How to make it converge without pretraining.

The point of the pretraining was that it makes the training more stable and we need less tuning of other hyper params. That is why it does not converge as-is when you just disable pretraining. You have to tune it much more.

Things to tune:

- the initialization matters much more
- learning rate (initial, warmup phase, further scheduling)
- regularization (dropout, L2, label smoothing) (maybe this also needs scheduling)